# Get value of same subkey of json file

Tags: python, json, pandas, list

I want to convert one json file format to another format.
input json file looks like,

```
json1 = {"Roll Number":{"0":"12345675890"},"Exam Code":{"0":"125"},"q1":{"0":"A"},"q2":{"0":"B"},"q3":{"0":"B"},"q4":{"0":"C"},"q5":{"0":"C"}
```

Here you can consider 0 as the 0th student (answersheet of first student)

I want this output format,

```
json2 = {
            "id": 1, 
            "Roll Number": 12345675890, 
            "Exam Code": 125,
            "qtn_ans_id": 1, #this is question number
            "field1": 0, 
            "field2": 0,
            "field3": 1, #if ans is C then field3=1 and else is 0
            "field4": 0,
        }
```

in json1 it contains 5 question answers and details and i want to convert it into json2, and my code is

`import json`

Stored json file into data

```
with open('json1.json') as data_file:
  data = json.load(data_file)
```

write default format

```
format = {"table": "omr",
    "rows":
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "regist_no": 1215152,
            "exam_id": 125,
            "qtn_ans_id": 1,
            "field1": 0,
            "field2": 0,
            "field3": 0,
            "field4": 0,    
        }
    ]
}
```

My dummy Code

```
json2 = {}

for (k, v) in data.items():
  if(k=='Roll Number'):
    format['rows'][0]['regist_no']=v['0']
  if(k=='Exam Code'):
     format['rows'][0]['exam_id'] = v['0']
  if(v['0']=='A'):
     format['rows'][0]['field1'] = 1
  elif(v['0']=='B'):
     format['rows'][0]['field2'] = 1
  elif(v['0']=='C'):
     format['rows'][0]['field3'] = 1
  elif(v['0']=='D'):
     format['rows'][0]['field4'] = 1


  json2.append(format['rows'])
```

wrong output i get is,

```
[{
   'field1': 1,
   'field2': 1,
   'field3': 1,
   'field4': 1
}]
```

All the field values are 1.
For answer A Right output can be,

```
[{
   'field1': 1,
   'field2': 0,
   'field3': 0,
   'field4': 0
}]
```

or is there any other way like using pandas data frame.
I know this is long and dummy question but i will be glade if anyone can help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
# assuming your json data looks like this:
json1 = [
    {
        "Roll Number" : {"0":"12345675890"},
        "Exam Code" : {"0":"125"},
        "q1" : {"0":"A"},
        "q2" : {"0":"B"},
        "q3" : {"0":"B"},
        "q4" : {"0":"C"},
        "q5" : {"0":"C"},
    },
    {
        "Roll Number" : {"0":"12345675891"},
        "Exam Code" : {"0":"125"},
        "q1" : {"0":"C"},
        "q2" : {"0":"B"},
        "q3" : {"0":"A"},
        "q4" : {"0":"C"},
        "q5" : {"0":"D"},
    },
]
```

Then:

```
# converts old question field to new question field:
def ConvertAnswer(question):

    # get letter answer from question:
    for key, value in question.items():
        letter = value

    # pack fields object:
    fields = {
        'field1' : 1 if letter == 'A' else 0, 
        'field2' : 1 if letter == 'B' else 0,
        'field3' : 1 if letter == 'C' else 0,
        'field4' : 1 if letter == 'D' else 0,
    }

    return fields


# iterate over each student:    
for student in json1:

    # iterate over each field in student:
    for key, value in student.items():

        # check for questions (check if key starts with 'q'):
        if key[0] == 'q':

            # replace question field in student object:
            student[key] = ConvertAnswer(value)
```

Will result in:

```
# output of json1:    
[{'Roll Number': {'0': '12345675890'},
  'Exam Code': {'0': '125'},
  'q1': {'field1': 1, 'field2': 0, 'field3': 0, 'field4': 0},
  'q2': {'field1': 0, 'field2': 1, 'field3': 0, 'field4': 0},
  'q3': {'field1': 0, 'field2': 1, 'field3': 0, 'field4': 0},
  'q4': {'field1': 0, 'field2': 0, 'field3': 1, 'field4': 0},
  'q5': {'field1': 0, 'field2': 0, 'field3': 1, 'field4': 0}},
 {'Roll Number': {'0': '12345675891'},
  'Exam Code': {'0': '125'},
  'q1': {'field1': 0, 'field2': 0, 'field3': 1, 'field4': 0},
  'q2': {'field1': 0, 'field2': 1, 'field3': 0, 'field4': 0},
  'q3': {'field1': 1, 'field2': 0, 'field3': 0, 'field4': 0},
  'q4': {'field1': 0, 'field2': 0, 'field3': 1, 'field4': 0},
  'q5': {'field1': 0, 'field2': 0, 'field3': 0, 'field4': 1}}]
```

Comment: Thank you I get it for fields. in json1 for two students it's format is, `json1 = [
    {
        "Roll Number" : {"0":"12345675890"},
        "Exam Code" : {"0":"125"},
        "q1" : {"0":"A"},
        "q2" : {"0":"B"},
        "q3" : {"0":"B"},
        "q4" : {"0":"C"},
        "q5" : {"0":"C"},
    },
    {
        "Roll Number" : {"1":"12345675891"},
        "Exam Code" : {"1":"125"},
        "q1" : {"1":"C"},
        "q2" : {"1":"B"},
        "q3" : {"1":"A"},
        "q4" : {"1":"C"},
        "q5" : {"1":"D"},
    }
]`for 2nd student index is 1 and not 0.

Comment: So how to append that 2nd student to output list with his roll number and fields?

Comment: I see - I've edited the code above - let me know if it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

My solution in more "pandasonic" than the other answer.

Start from defining a function, which will be used to change
the answer code to 4 answer columns:

```
def ans(code):
    return pd.Series([ int(code == x) for x in 'ABCD' ],
        index=[ 'field' + str(i) for i in range(1, 5)])
```

Read your input file into a DataFrame as follows:

```
with open('input.json') as data_file:
    df = pd.read_json(data_file, orient='columns')
```

Then reformat it, saving in another DataFrame:

```
df2 = pd.wide_to_long(df.rename_axis(index='id').reset_index(),
    stubnames='q', i='Roll Number', j='qtn_ans_id').reset_index()\
    .reindex(columns=['id', 'Roll Number', 'Exam Code', 'qtn_ans_id', 'q'])
```

For now it contains one column *q* with answer codes.
So to change it into 4 columns for each field, run:

```
df2 = df2.join(df2.q.apply(ans)).drop(columns=['q'])
```

And the last step is to create the output JSON string:

```
df2.to_json(orient='records')
```

which you can e.g. save in an output file.

**Note:** If your input contained e.g. data for 2 students,
the JSON file should have the following form:

```
{
  "Roll Number":{"0":12345675890,"1":23456758901},
  "Exam Code":{"0":125,"1":125},
  "q1":{"0":"A","1":"A"},
  "q2":{"0":"B","1":"B"},
  "q3":{"0":"B","1":"C"},
  "q4":{"0":"C","1":"D"},
  "q5":{"0":"C","1":"C"}
}
```

(different than the input format proposed in the other answer).